# Carregar página inteira ao clicar em link dentro de Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Olá,

Tenho um Iframe da seguinte forma:

```
<iframe width="230" height="280" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://impressoearte.com/produto-em-destaque/" target="_top" ></iframe>
```

O que quero fazer:

Este iframe chama o produto de uma página especifica dentro de uma parte do site principal, a página especifica é esta: http://impressoearte.com/produto-em-destaque/

Este produto contem um link na imagem para visualizar mais detalhes deste produto. Preciso que ao clicar nesta imagem do produto a página principal seja carregada para a página do produto e não somente o bloco em que o iframe se encontra. Preciso de uma solução que não precise saber o link que vai estar na imagem do produto, ou seja, independente do link da imagem do produto o carregamento seja feito.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tiver acesso ao código *HTML* da página em questão, a solução é bem simples. Basta adicionar um atributo `target` no link com valor `_blank` que nesse caso você abre o link em outra página:

```html
<a href="http://impressoearte.com/produto-em-destaque/" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://impressoearte.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/exaustor-510x510.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Mas caso queira abrir na mesma, basta utilizar o valor [`_parent`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp):

```html
<a href="http://impressoearte.com/produto-em-destaque/" target="_parent">
   <img src="http://impressoearte.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/exaustor-510x510.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Você ainda pode tentar com javascript:

```html
<a href="http://impressoearte.com/produto-em-destaque/" onclick="return irParaPaginaAcima(this.href)">
   <img src="http://impressoearte.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/exaustor-510x510.jpg"/>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var irParaPaginaAcima = function irParaPaginaAcima (link) {
        window.parent.location = link;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Em navegadores mais recentes, nada disso vai funcionar se você não permitir. Para fazer isso você precisa setar o atributo [`sandbox`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) no `iframe` com o valor correspondente a o que você quer liberar.

```
<!-- Para habilitar a navegação por target="_parent" -->
<iframe sandbox="allow-top-navigation" ... />


<!-- Para habilitar a navegação por javascript (window.location = url) -->
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" ... />
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: se eu colocar um target apenas vou abrir o link em uma nova aba, não é isto que desejo. Preciso fazer com que seja carregado na mesma página onde o iframe se encontra, mas não somente dentro do bloco (div) do iframe, mas na página toda.

Comment: Você quer abrir o link na mesma página, é isso?

Comment: isso mesmo. Preciso fazer com que seja carregado na mesma página onde o iframe se encontra, mas não somente dentro do bloco (div) do iframe, mas na página toda.

Comment: Bom, nesse caso você pode utilizar o valor `_parent`. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Entendi, eu tentei usar o valor     _parent     dentro do código do iframe, mas não deu certo. Quanto a editar a página que o iframe chama eu não vou ter acesso a ela.

Comment: Parece existir alguma configuração de segurança que não permite uma página filha (`iframe`) interferir no comportamento da mãe

Comment: E tem como contornar isto?

Comment: como eu ja havia dito desde o começo, eu não vou ter acesso para editar a pagina filho (src do iframe). Sendo assim não tem como eu inserir seu javascript. O produto vem do woocommerce.

Comment: Consegui uma solução, estou editando a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, infelizmente ainda não posso votar na sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode criar um CSS e na classe exemplo:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .framepdf {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<iframe class="framePdf" src="http://impressoearte.com/produto-em-destaque/"> </iframe>
```